# why would curl and wget result in a 403 forbidden?

Tags: wget, curl

I try to download a file with `wget` and `curl` and it is rejected with a 403 error (forbidden).

I can view the file using the web browser on the same machine.

I try again with my browser's user agent, obtained by http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com. I do this:

```
wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0' http://...
```

and

```
curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0' http://...
```

but it is still forbidden. What other reasons might there be for the 403, and what ways can I alter the `wget` and `curl` commands to overcome them?

(this is not about being able to get the file - I know I can just save it from my browser; it's about understanding why the command-line tools work differently)

**update**

Thanks to all the excellent answers given to this question. The specific problem I had encountered was that the server was checking the referrer. By adding this to the command-line I could get the file using `curl` and `wget`.

The server that checked the referrer bounced through a 302 to another location that performed no checks at all, so a `curl` or `wget` of that site worked cleanly.

If anyone is interested, this came about because I was reading [this](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/font-face-in-base64-is-cross-browser-compatible) page to learn about embedded CSS and was trying to look at the site's css for an example. The actual URL I was getting trouble with was [this](http://cloud.typography.com/610186/691184/css/fonts.css) and the `curl` I ended up with is

```
curl -L -H 'Referer: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/font-face-in-base64-is-cross-browser-compatible/' http://cloud.typography.com/610186/691184/css/fonts.css
```

and the wget is

```
 wget --referer='http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/font-face-in-base64-is-cross-browser-compatible/' http://cloud.typography.com/610186/691184/css/fonts.css
```

Very interesting.

Comment: Pages that check referer are really annoying. The header is supposed to be optional and used for gathering statistics.

Comment: The easiest thing I've found is to convert it to a zip file and use it that way.

Comment: ERROR 403 may also occur when checking timestamps with **`wget -N`**. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62176110/658497

Comment: FWIW I had a similar error message when downloading a URL that had access tokens embedded in it, and it was fixed when I enclosed the full URL with quotation marks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A HTTP request may contain more headers that are not set by curl or wget. For example:

- Cookie: this is the most likely reason why a request would be rejected, I have seen this happen on download sites. Given a cookie `key=val`, you can set it with the `-b key=val` (or `--cookie key=val`) option for `curl`.
- Referer (sic): when clicking a link on a web page, most browsers tend to send the current page as referrer. It should not be relied on, but even eBay failed to reset a password when this header was absent. So yes, it may happen. The `curl` option for this is `-e URL` and `--referer URL`.
- Authorization: this is becoming less popular now due to the uncontrollable UI of the username/password dialog, but it is still possible. It can be set in `curl` with the `-u user:password` (or `--user user:password`) option.
- User-Agent: some requests will yield different responses depending on the User Agent. This can be used in a good way (providing the real download rather than a list of mirrors) or in a bad way (reject user agents which do not start with `Mozilla`, or contain `Wget` or `curl`).

You can normally use the Developer tools of your browser (Firefox and Chrome support this) to read the headers sent by your browser. If the connection is not encrypted (that is, not using HTTPS), then you can also use a packet sniffer such as Wireshark for this purpose.

Besides these headers, websites may also trigger some actions behind the scenes that change state. For example, when opening a page, it is possible that a request is performed on the background to prepare the download link. Or a redirect happens on the page. These actions typically make use of Javascript, but there may also be a hidden frame to facilitate these actions.

If you are looking for a method to easily fetch files from a download site, have a look at plowdown, included with [plowshare](https://code.google.com/p/plowshare/).

Comment: Another really perverse possibility would be that the server for some reason was configured to return 403 instead of 200 on success.

Comment: This gave me the clue I needed. After trying cookies, I found the referrer to be the problem (now, if only that could be spelt properly!!!)

Comment: If it is *still failing* in `wget` try adding `--auth-no-challenge`. Works like magic.

Comment: The `--referer` option solved my problem.

Comment: One more possibility is that you do not have read permissions on the file on the server hosing the files. Using `chmod` to provide read permission resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 43):

Tried all of the above however no luck; used dev browser tool to get user-agent string, once I added the following, success:

```
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: worked like a charm !!

Comment: This is what worked for me too, but a shorter user agent name is also probably fine, e.g. "Mozilla". https://stackoverflow.com/a/37021939/1718491

Answer (score 18):

Just want to add to the above answers that you could use the "Copy as cURL" feature present in Chrome developer tools (since v26.0) and Firebug (since [v1.12](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/firebug-1-12-new-features/#copyAsCURL)). You can access this feature right-clicking the request row in the Network tab.

Comment: This helped immensely, especially the tools in Chrome. When I tried in firefox, the request header after the 302 was all I could see. In Chromium I could see both and this gave me the info to solve the problem.

Comment: @starfry You need to tick `Enable persistent logs` on the settings tab of Firefox's dev tools to prevent it from clearing network logs on a redirect. Chrome has a similar option. Incidentally, "Copy as cURL" has been in Firefox Nightly/Aurora/Beta for a while now, and is due next major release (31.0).

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you're asking for, it could be a cookie.  With Firefox, you can do a right-click when you're on the page in question, "View Page Info". Choose "Security" icon, and then click "View Cookies" button.

For puzzling out cookies, the Firefox "Live HTTP Headers" plug-in is essential. You can see what cookies get set, and what cookies get sent back to the web server.

`wget` can work with cookies, but it's totally infuriating, as it doesn't give a hint that it didn't send cookies. Your best bet is to remove all related cookies from your browser, and go through whatever initial login or page viewing sequence it takes.  Look at "Live HTTP Headers" for cookies, and for any POST or GET parameters. Do the first login step with `wget` using "--keep-session-cookies" and "--save-cookies" options. That will give you a cookie file you can look at with a text editor. Use `wget --load-cookies` with the cookie file for the next steps.

Comment: I tested without cookies in Firefox by opening a *private browsing window* and, as expected I got the 403 error. Interesting that you don't get the error in a new tab. In Chromium, a new tab returns the 403.

Comment: Incidentally, you can use the network tab of Firefox's dev tools to inspect sent and received cookies without any addons. Ditto for Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: @bob - yes I found that. It took me a few minutes as it wasn't something. Firebug has Copy as CURL now but it would be nice to see it the native tools too.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason this can happen is if the site requires SSL. Your browser will automatically forward from HTTP to HTTPS but curl and wget will not. So try the request with HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: This would end in error 301 or 302, Redirect, if I am right.