# curl wget - 403 Forbidden

Tags: wget, curl

I am trying to download a site as you see bellow with curl or wget but either one seems to work. I tried different options like "curl -k" seemed promising, but did not work. Every one is allowed to visit the page, it works with Firefox. I also check [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139698/why-would-curl-and-wget-result-in-a-403-forbidden) for answers but did not find one, although I think it is a similar problem.

--

### curl "https://cdburnerxp.se/en/development"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either it is a 403 page. You are not allowed. Or you can use a user agent such as this.

```
wget --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/600.1.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.17" http://website.com
```

It will allow you to access some websites. If this doesn't work then your are probably not allowed to visit the link.

Comment: Everyone is allowed to visit, it works with Firefox. If I do `code`(curl -k "http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/") it works fine

Comment: Ok, did you try it with a user agent?

Comment: Sorry, what is a user agent?

Comment: It makes the the website think that you are on a browser.

Comment: I just tried `code`(curl --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0" "https://cdburnerxp.se/en/development")  but it does not work.

Comment: I guess it is not possible to download the page https://cdburnerxp.se/en/development with linux :(

Comment: You have to type out a longer agent. Copy my code.

Comment: And add the website at the end instead of `http://website.com`

Comment: I did: 
`wget --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/600.1.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.17" "https://cdburnerxp.se/en/development" `

   and get  :  

`--2014-10-03 08:58:46--  https://cdburnerxp.se/en/development
Resolving cdburnerxp.se... 176.9.56.74, 2a01:4f8:150:84c2::2
Connecting to cdburnerxp.se|176.9.56.74|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-10-03 08:58:47 ERROR 403: Forbidden.`
`

Comment: I did this, `wget --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/600.1.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.17" cdburnerxp.se/en/development` And it worked.