# GCP wget (and curl) fails to download file Error 403

Tags: curl, wget, google-cloud

I started using GCP (Google Cloud Platform) recently. I created an Ubuntu VM in Google Cloud Engine, and wanted to download some files from a website via wget.

I am able to download it using a normal webbrowser on my windows computer and also using wget in a WSL Ubuntu kernel, which I installed in my local windows computer.

I'm using the following command:

```
 wget -c --tries=0 -O sample.zip --user-agent="Mozilla" --referer="https://ida.loni.usc.edu/<.......>" --accept="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" https://<.....url.....>.zip
```

And it gives me the following error:

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403
ERROR 403: (no description).

I've tried several other commands, such like trying different user-agent values, without user-agent and without referer. But it also does not work.

Lastly, I've also tried using curl and a python script, but with no success. Everything ends up in the same 403 (forbidden) error.

I already read the post [why would curl and wget result in a 403 forbidden?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139698/why-would-curl-and-wget-result-in-a-403-forbidden) and some similar ones, which talk about solutions for this 403 error problem. However, none of them worked for me.

My guess is that I am missing out something on my firewall configuration or in my request header.

**UPDATE:**

The files I want to download are large, they are over 500mb.
Apparently, I am able to download a small metadata zip file from the https://ida.loni.usc.edu/ domain.

Any guesses on that?

Also, I already included a firwall rule to allow external IPs.

Comment: I haven't been using GCP in a while, have you check you can use outgoing traffic from  GCP ? (firewalls and private network on google's console ? )

Comment: I remember I have set a firewall rule to allow https 0.0.0.0/0 external IPs. But I'll take another look and get back here asap.

Comment: Revised the firewall rules. It still does not work. =/